# Deduce stability from strict convexity of gradient systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, gradient-flows

Given a twice differentiable function $f(x):\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R$, and its corresponding  gradient system $$\dot x=-\nabla f(x)$$

My question is:

If $f(x)$ is strictly convex, can we conclude that all trajectories will converge to the unique global minimum (i.e. the unique global minimum is globally asymptotically equilibrium)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strict convexity is not enough as it may not guarantee the existence of am equilibrium point. For instance $f(x)=e^{-x}$ is strictly convex.

So, you will need

- strict convexity and the existence of a minimum for $f$, or
- strong convexity.

Assume that the minimum is 0 and is attained at $x^*=0$, then $f$ is positive definite. We can therefore consider the function

$$V(x)=f(x)$$

which is obviously positive definite. Then, we have that

$$\dot{V}(x)=-||\nabla f(x)||_2^2$$

which is negative definite since $\nabla f(x)=0$ if and only if $x=0$. So, we have the local convergence to the equilibrium point.

To have the global convergence, we need the radial unboundedness. This is automatically achieved $f$ is strongly convex or $f$ is strictly convex under the assumption of positive definiteness of $f$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I understand it now, and I'm waiting for the strict convex case about globally convergence.

Comment: The easy fix is strict convexity + existence of a minimum + radial unboundedness.

Comment: I founded this paper (Strong Convexity Does Not Imply Radial Unboundedness) gives that strongly convex function can either be radially unbounded or unbounded below in every neighborhood. Thus for the case of strongly convexity, in order to use Lasalle theorem to prove global stability, we may need to exclude the later case.. (Not sure, am I right?)

Comment: Please always read the papers first. It is mostly about infinite-dimensional spaces, the finite-dimensional case is perfectly fine.

Comment: It seems to me that: the only trouble is the existence of uniqueness of global minimum, instead of the radial unboundedness because lemma 4.1 in this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.02070.pdf) guarantees that if $f$ is convex (and positive definite), then $f$ is radially unbounded. Not necessary to be strict or strongly convex. Being strict convex & existence of local minimum, or strongly convex is to make sure the existence of unique global minimum.

Comment: Yes, that is fine.